# Stack trace references location that does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a stack trace logged on a dev server. In the stack trace it makes a reference to a file location on my local computer and not the file location on the dev server.

Has anyone seen this before? Here is an partial example of what I am getting (some names changed to generic versions):

```
at Project_Service.Specific.ServersService.GetServers() in C:\Projects\XXX\MAIN\Project\Dashboard_v2.0\src\Project\Project_Service\Specific\ServersService.cs:line 51
at Project_Web.Controllers.ServersController.Index() in C:\Projects\XXX\MAIN\Project\Dashboard_v2.0\src\Project\Project_Web\Controllers\ServersController.cs:line 32
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
```

The C:\Projects folder is on my local computer. On the dev server it is a completely different location.
The website was published from within Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace file locations are based on the locations within the .PDB, which is created at compile time.

If you publish the .PDB, it will use file paths based on the system in which the code is *compiled*, not *executed*.

Comment: Yep this was it. I deleted the .PDB files and the locations are no longer are logged.